# Why doesnt my javascript trigger the different css3 animation delays Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-10

```
document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded",function(){
        var e, t=document.querySelectorAll("div.bounceInDown");
        for(var n=0,r=t.length;n<r;n++){
            e=Math.round(Math.random()*7e3)+"ms";
            t[n].style.animationDelay=e;
            t[n].style.WebkitAnimationDelay=e
        }
    },
    false
)
```

This code is in the head of my document. I also tried it in the body and bottom. No method works. I also tried the JQuery ready method.

This is code I found online and with MUCH luck. Had to make a few changes so it works in chrome though. What can I do to make it work in Internet Explorer 10?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `WebkitAnimationDelay` property. As the name already states its for [Webkit browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) only. As you can [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp), using the statement without `Webkit` should work for other browsers with CSS3 support aswell.

Comment: No, this is not the issue. I have my CSS animations with all vendor prefixes and unprefixed. The animation also works in all browsers, just my javascript doesnt work. All my content with the "bounceInDown" div should fire off with seperate delays.